# Looping through NSArray on firebase to retrieve Strings

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, parsing, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on an app where a user can have a list of users that they have in there group. The users are represented on Firebase as an NSArray as Strings(userID)presented as such:

```
-members: 
    -0: :"intihntgnginfignrgrr"
    -1: "lkoirgningitngitihnti"
    -2: "jgnhngbngnbinbnbknntn"
```

I would like to retrieve all users that are "members" of this group and display their details but I am receiving the following error from Xcode 9 while parsing.

> Cannot convert value of type 'NSArray' to expected argument type 'String.Element' (aka 'Character')

Below is how I am attempting to parse:

```
if creator == userID {
    let members = watchlist.childSnapshot(forPath: "members").value as! NSArray
    self.Firebase_REference_users.observeSingleEvent(of: DataEventType.value, with: { (usersnap) in
        guard let usersnap = usersnap.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {return}
        for allUsers in usersnap {
            let alluserids = allUsers.key
            if alluserids.contains(members) {
                let name = allUsers.childSnapshot(forPath: "userName").value as! String
                let users = User(profileImg: "userProfile", username: name)
                wgroup.append(users)
            }
        }
   )}
}
```

Comment: `let name = allUsers.childSnapshot(forPath: "userName").value` is not a String as described by the error.. You need to re-analyze your data structure and modify your code according to that.

Comment: Try printing the type of your `name` like `type(of:allUsers.childSnapshot(forPath: "userName").value)`

Comment: The value was set as String.I figured it out by getting the user IDs from the the the members of the list and setting and If "current" user is member of that list..Much easier then trying to get the user out go the members Array...

Comment: Good to see you have solution. :)